# Theorem of Alternatives proof only one of the systems is solvable

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, duality-theorems

Let $ A \in R^{nxm}$, $x \in R^n$,  $c,y \in R^m$ show that, either

I) $Ax=c$

II) $A^Ty=0, c^Ty=1$

is solvable

I'm completely new to the theorem of alternatives, so my attempt is:

If I is solvable then $Ax=c$ if I multiply that by $y$ then
$(Ax)^Ty = c^Ty = 1$

since $(Ax)^T \in R^n$ and $y \in R^m$ then they cannot be multiplied and thus we reach a contradiction and II is not solvable

I'm not sure if my way is correct or is there a more sophisticated way to prove it, and also I'm having a hard time trying to prove the other way around (i.e. when II is solvable). It would also be great if someone can recommend for me something to read to understand the theorem intuitively. Thanks

Comment: Presumably, $A$ and $c$ are fixed, and a solution is $x$ or $y?$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I assume this is correct yes

Comment: Already the multiplication $Ax$ doesn't make sense. You've swapped $m$ and $n$.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the multiplication property of transpose: supposing both systems have solutions, we get a contradiction:
$$0\ =\ x^TA^Ty\ =\ (Ax)^Ty\ =\ c^Ty\ =\ 1\,.$$

If $Ax=c$ doesn't have a solution, it means that $c$ is not in the image (=column space) of $A$. 
Then consider the orthogonal decomposition $c=c_1+c_2$ where $c_1\in{\rm im}(A)$ and $c_2\perp{\rm im}(A)$.
This last condition means exactly that $A^Tc_2=0$ (i.e. $c_2$ is orthogonal to every columns of $A$).

Note that $c_2=0$ would imply $c=c_1\in{\rm im}(A)$ which case we are now excluding.

Then, $c^Tc_2=(c_1+c_2)^Tc_2=c_2^Tc_2=\|c_2\|^2\ne 0$, so we can take $y:=\frac{c_2}{c_2^Tc_2}$.

If $A^Ty=0,\ c^Ty=1$ doesn't have solution, it means that $c\in{\rm im}(A)$, i.e. $c_2=0$ in the above decomposition, as otherwise the above process yields a solution.